# Как выйти на соседний элемент через xpath

Tags: xpath

При вводе в метод text1, в ответ нужно получить элемент div с text1.1, при вводе в метод text2 соответcвенно text2.1. Как можно зная название text1 выйти на соседний элемент text1.1? Как такое через xpath сделать?

```html
<div id='1H62FE09A'>
  <div class='MyClassName0'>
    <div>text2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='MyClassName1'>
    <div>text2.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='MyClassName2'>
    <div>text5</div>
  </div>
  <div class='MyClassName3'>
    <div>text5.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='MyClassName4'>
    <div>text7</div>
  </div>
  <div class='MyClassName5'>
    <div>text7.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='MyClassName6'>
    <div>text1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='MyClassName7'>
    <div>text1.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='MyClassName8'>
    <div>text8</div>
  </div>
  <div class='MyClassName9'>
    <div>text8.1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='MyClassName10'>
    <div>text10</div>
  </div>
  <div class='MyClassName11'>
    <div>text10.1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Слизано [отсюда](https://software-testing.ru/forum/index.php?/topic/35228-kak-najti-element-sleduiuschij-za-tekuschim-na-odnom/) .

Для примера

```
<td>
    <span>Значение1</span>
</td>
<td>
    <span>Данные2</span>
</td>
<td>
    <span>Значение2</span>
</td>
```

решение

```
//td/span[text()='Данные2']/following::td[1]/span
```